# Bash script doubt - How can I automatically update the hwclock with NTP when I have internet connection

Tags: bash, ntp

Bash script in
[How can I automatically update the hwclock with NTP when I have internet connection](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9791/how-can-i-automatically-update-the-hwclock-with-ntp-when-i-have-internet-connect)
seems not to run as expected in Raspbian Stretch 9.4

The log file will be created with the first reading but no more readings will be appended to the file.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ ls -al hwc*
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi   84 Jul 31 18:40 hwcsynch.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 1783 Jul 31 18:39 hwcsynch.sh
```

crontab -e to have the script run every minute for testing purposes:

```
* * * * * /home/pi/hwcsynch.sh
```

Only the first reading is added to the file. Following readings will not.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ cat hwcsynch.log
Tue 31 Jul 18:40:02 CEST 2018: Connection to time-server. HwClock difference: 1 sec
```

And then run the bash script from prompt just to make sure it works:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ ./hwcsynch.sh
Connection to time-server
---------------------------------
HwClock: 1533055729 sec
SysClock: 1533055728 sec
---------------------------------
Difference: 1 sec
```

So I assume the script is running properly. Maybe it has to do with...?

```
if !(awk '/./{line=$0} END{print line}' $LOGFILE | grep -q "$msgConnection") || [ "$secDiff" -gt "$maxDiffSec" ]; then
        echo $(date)": "$msgConnection". "$msgDiff >> $LOGFILE
fi
```

Comment: Do **NOTHING** and it should work.

Comment: what and where are `$msgConnection`, `$secDiff`, `$maxDiffSec`, `$msgDiff`  and `$LOGFILE` defined?

Comment: try `* * * * * /home/pi/hwcsynch.sh > /tmp/last_hwsync` in the crontab. It will give you the stdout of the script which will probably give a better understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in the comment: put

```
* * * * * /home/pi/hwcsynch.sh > /tmp/last_hwsync
```

in the crontab. The result was:

```
$ cat /tmp/last_hwsynch 
Connection to time-server 
--------------------------------- 
HwClock: 1533155224 sec 
SysClock: 1533155223 sec 
--------------------------------- 
Difference: 1 sec
```

Looking at the script that is referenced:

```
if [ "$secDiff" -gt "$maxDiffSec" ] ; then
            echo "---------------------------------"
            echo "The difference between Hw- and Sys-Clock is more than $maxDiffSec sec."
            echo "Hw-Clock will be updated"
```

This means that the clock is only updated if the difference > $maxDiffSec, which is set to 2 earlier in the script. So no further action will be taken.

Answer (score 0):

@LjmDullaart I have done it as you suggest:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ cat /tmp/last_hwsynch  
Connection to time-server  
---------------------------------  
HwClock: 1533155224 sec  
SysClock: 1533155223 sec  
---------------------------------  
Difference: 1 sec
```

Every time I can that fie I notice time moves forward, so yes, the script works. I have achieved the same goal by ./hwcsynch.sh

After cat'ing the script log now I notice:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ cat hwcsynch.log
Tue 31 Jul 18:40:02 CEST 2018: Connection to time-server. HwClock difference: 1 sec
Tue 31 Jul 19:08:01 CEST 2018: No connection to time-server
Tue 31 Jul 19:15:04 CEST 2018: Connection to time-server. HwClock difference: 1 sec
Tue 31 Jul 21:04:01 CEST 2018: No connection to time-server
Tue 31 Jul 23:37:03 CEST 2018: Connection to time-server. HwClock difference: 1 sec
Wed 1 Aug 00:57:01 CEST 2018: No connection to time-server
Wed 1 Aug 05:56:04 CEST 2018: Connection to time-server. HwClock difference: 1 sec
Wed 1 Aug 08:40:01 CEST 2018: No connection to time-server
Wed 1 Aug 17:07:02 CEST 2018: Connection to time-server. HwClock difference: 1 sec
Wed 1 Aug 19:32:01 CEST 2018: No connection to time-server
Wed 1 Aug 19:38:02 CEST 2018: Connection to time-server. HwClock difference: 1 sec
```

Strange... at 05:56:04 yes I switched on the router, the Pi went online and connected to time-server and so it is reflected in the log. However, the next time mark in the next line is at 08:40:01 stating no connection. Weird as I switched off the router at about 06:30:00 so just about that time the log should have a line reading no connection when in fact the log shows that has taken place at 08:40:01. So something's not right.

@JaromandaX those are defined in the bash script by Thomas (link in first message):

```
msgConnection="Connection to time-server"
secDiff=$(($secHwClock-$secSysClock))
# Set the maximum allowed difference in seconds between Hw-Clock and Sys-Clock
maxDiffSec="2"
msgDiff="HwClock difference: $secDiff sec"
LOGFILE="/home/pi/hwcsynch.log"
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.